# Validation not working on form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to switch the submit button off when the user enters something on the email area (and obviously being validated) but for some reason it ain't working.

What's wrong with my validation?

```
function validateEmail(email) {

    var btnSubmit = document.getElementById("submitButton");


var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

 btnSubmit.disabled = !(validateEmail(email));


}
```

What am I doing wrong? The function is called when the area when the user inputs changes(onchange=("validateEmail(email);");

//////After I was given a solution, I tried it and the JavaScript worked! () but I think I'm making a wrong calling of something because I'm getting this on my alert:

.Disabled the button as the email you have entered is invalid.: [object HTMLInputElement]

Here's how I called it.

And the JavaScript is the fiddle that was given on the solution.

Comment: function doesn't return any value?

Comment: Am I having trouble reading this on my phone, or is your function infinitely recursing?

Comment: I feel this function should be  infinitely recursing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### problems with the code:

#### 1. Function doesn't do any validation.

Your function is doing nothing rather than recursively calling itself everytime.

#### 2. You are not using the created regular expression

The regular expression you made for email is not used to check the email string is valid or not.

### solution:

You should use the regex made for checking whether the email string is valid or not. And apply the consequences accordingly.

```
function validateEmail(email) {

    var btnSubmit = document.getElementById("submitButton");
    var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if( re.test(email) ){
        return true;
    } else {
        btnSubmit.disabled = true;
        return false;
    }
    


}
```

here is a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rW7ru/1/)

Comment: Thank you, it appears to work...One last thing...When I return the alert, it doesn't return the email the user gave, here's how Im calling it.

Is this the proper way?

<input type="text" name="email" id="email" required size="40" value="" placeholder="me@example.com" onchange="validateEmail(email);" /> And here's what alert told me ".Disabled the button as the email you have entered is invalid. :[object HTMLInputElement]" Thank you for your time man!